# C-Index for few failure cases

Tags: survival, cox-model, censoring

I'm training a Cox model on top of a CNN to predict the overall survival of head and neck cancer patients based on CT images.
In order to rate the models performance I'm using Harrel's C-Index.

To get a feeling of the baseline performance I generated some random prediction for the validation data.
This random prediction already yields a pretty high C-Index > 0.7.
My feeling is, that this stems from the fact that the data contains only few failure cases.
Because survival chances are pretty high and a lot of data points are right censored.

So, my question is:

1. is it the case that few failure cases give a high baseline C-Index
2. what's the best/common way to measure the models performance in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harrell has two L's.

The c-index works fine in the rare outcome case.  It is not prevalence-dependent, but its standard error will be properly large to account for the fact that you have limited information upon which to estimate the concordance probability.  Be sure to accompany all estimates with the standard error, which is computed in the R `survival` package or the `Hmisc` package `rcorr.cens` function.

Note that the c-index is not the very best way to measure predictive discrimination.  See http://fharrell.com/post/addvalue

There is a general problem when the number of events is not large (e.g., is not at least 15 times the number of predictors): overfitting.   This will inflate the c-index (and other measures).   You can use the bootstrap to correct c for overfitting, e.g., using the `validate` function in the `rms` package.

Comment: This answer highlights I do not understand when to potentially use the concordance index. Is its use better in descriptive statistics when you want to see if a simple model can “explain” some variates? Is there a good resource for learning about the c-index?

Comment: See [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) book and course notes.  The c-index is used to quantify the pure predictive discrimination of a single model.  For binary Y it is easy to understand: pair every observation with Y=1 with every observation with Y=0.  Compute the fraction of pairs for which the one with Y=1 had a higher predicted probability than the one with Y=0.  It doesn't deal with explanation per se.